# Can ETL informatica Big Data edition (not the cloud version) connect to Cloudera Impala?

Tags: hadoop, informatica, cloudera-cdh, informatica-powercenter, impala

We are trying do a proof of concept on Informatica Big Data edition (not the cloud version) and I have seen that we might be able to use HDFS, Hive as source and target. But my question is does Informatica connect to Cloudera Impala? If so, do we need to have any additional connector for that? I have done comprehensive research to check if this is supported but could not find anything. Did anyone already try this? If so, can you specify the steps and link to any documentation?

Informatica version: 9.6.1 (Hotfix 2)

Comment: Any updates on this? I am also interested in HBase connection

Answer (score 3):

You can use the odbc driver provided by cloudera.

http://www.cloudera.com/downloads/connectors/impala/odbc/2-5-22.html

For Irene, the you can use the same driver the above one is based the simba driver.

http://www.simba.com/drivers/hbase-odbc-jdbc/