# Does Informatica Big Data edition support Impala?

Tags: informatica, impala

Does Informatica BDE support Impala using any connector.

I can see that Informatica Cloud version support Impala through Hadoop Connector.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can ETL informatica Big Data edition (not the cloud version) connect to Cloudera Impala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34443789/can-etl-informatica-big-data-edition-not-the-cloud-version-connect-to-cloudera)

Comment: @Amos: Another question doesn't have a concrete answer.